# How does angulars $watch function work with slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider, angularjs-ng-repeat

everyone. I am new to Web Development and I encountered a problem. I finally managed to create a fiddle of my problem to get more specific.

My Problem is that I have 2 Slider. One Slider is responsible for a value and another one for weight. Those sliders are repeated with the ng-repeat function n times. In the fiddle only two times, for demonstration purposes.

I would like to calculate an index which consists of the following formula:

```
Value1*Weight1+Value2*Weight2
```

The index is calculated with the reduce function. **The Problem is: The index value is not updating when the value change due to the slider changes** 
I am pretty certain it should work with the $watch function, but I have unfortunately no clue how to manage this.

If someone could be so kind and provide me some help.

The js fiddle is linked below.

https://jsfiddle.net/dkyun/dfx0grdr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refactor your code with something like this:

```
  $scope.index = 0;

  $scope.calcIndex = function(){
    return $scope.alerts.reduce(function(prev, next) {
      return prev + (next.value*next.weight);  
    }, 0);
  };

  $scope.$watch(function(){
    return $scope.calcIndex();
  }, function(newValue){
    $scope.index = newValue;
  });
```

[CHECK THE DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/87hLao2d/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the index property on your scope based on changes to the alerts, you should do a deep watch on alerts:

```
$scope.$watch('alerts', function() {
    var index = $scope.alerts.reduce(function(prev, next) {
      return prev + (next.value*next.weight);  
    }, 0);

    $scope.index = index;
    console.log(index);
}, true);
```